# Using matlab to obtain the vector fields and the angles made by the vector field on a closed curve?

Tags: matlab, vector

Here is the given system I want to plot and obtain the vector field and the angles they make with the x axis. I want to find the index of a closed curve.

[image: The system]

[image: The system]

[image: The closed curve]

I know how to do this theoretically by choosing convenient points and see how the vector looks like at that point. Also I can always use

[image: angles]

to compute the angles. However I am having trouble trying to code it. Please don't mark me down if the question is unclear. I am asking it the way I understand it. I am new to matlab. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty hard challenge for someone new to matlab, I would recommend taking on some smaller challenges first to get you used to matlab's conventions.

That said, Matlab is all about numerical solutions so, unless you want to go down the symbolic maths route (and in that case I would probably opt for Mathematica instead), your first task is to decide on the limits and granularity of your simulated space, then define them so you can apply your system of equations to it.

There are lots of ways of doing this - some more efficient - but for ease of understanding I propose this:

Define the axes individually first

```
xpts = -10:0.1:10;
ypts = -10:0.1:10;
tpts = 0:0.01:10;
```

The a:b:c syntax gives you the lower limit (a), the upper limit (c) and the spacing (b), so you'll get 201 points for the x. You could use the `linspace` notation if that suits you better, look it up by typing `doc linspace` into the matlab console.

Now you can create a grid of your coordinate points. You actually end up with three 3d matrices, one holding the x-coords of your space and the others holding the y and t. They look redundant, but it's worth it because you can use matrix operations on them.

```
[XX, YY, TT] = meshgrid(xpts, ypts, tpts);
```

From here on you can perform whatever operations you like on those matrices. So to compute x^2.y you could do

```
x2y = XX.^2 .* YY;
```

remembering that you'll get a 3d matrix out of it and all the slices in the third dimension (corresponding to t) will be the same.

**Some notes**

Matlab has a good builtin help system. You can type 'help functionname' to get a quick reminder in the console or 'doc functionname' to open the help browser for details and examples. They really are very good, they'll help enormously.

I used XX and YY because that's just my preference, but I avoid single-letter variable names as a general rule. You don't have to.

Matrix multiplication is the default so if you try to do `XX*YY` you won't get the answer you expect! To do element-wise multiplication use the `.*` operator instead. This will do a11 = b11*c11, a12 = b12*c12, ...

To raise each element of the matrix to a given power use `.^`rather than `^` for similar reasons. Likewise division.

You have to make sure your matrices are the correct size for your operations. To do elementwise operations on matrices they have to be the same size. To do matrix operations they have to follow the matrix rules on sizing, as will the output. You will find the `size()` function handy for debugging.

Plotting vector fields can be done with `quiver`. To plot the components separately you have more options: `surf`, `contour` and others. Look up the help docs and they will link to similar types. The `plot` family are mainly about lines so they aren't much help for fields without creative use of the markers, colours and alpha.

To plot the curve, or any other contour, you don't have to test the values of a matrix - it won't work well anyway because of the granularity - you can use the `contour` plot with specific contour values.

Solving systems of dynamic equations is completely possible, but you will be doing a numeric simulation and your results will again be subject to the granularity of your grid. If you have closed form solutions, like your phi expression, they may be easier to work with conceptually but harder to get working in matlab.

This kind of problem is tractable in matlab but it involves some non-basic uses which are pretty hard to follow until you've got your head round Matlab's syntax. I would advise to start with a 2d grid instead

```
[XX, YY] = meshgrid(xpts, ypts);
```

and compute some functions of that like x^2.y or x^2 - y^2. Get used to plotting them using `quiver` or plotting the coordinates separately in intensity maps or surfaces.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and this explanation. I really appreciate it. I will read this more thoroughly and proceed. Thank you again immensely.

Comment: It's a pleasure, I hope it helps : )